# Dynamically access instance method

Tags: python

So I have a little script in python and for the help I want to print each method docstring. For example

```
~$ myscript.py help update
```

would print `myClass.update.__doc__` to the screen. The code I was trying to run is this:

```
import sys


class myClass:

    def update(self):
        """ update method help """

    def help(self):
        method = sys.argv[2:3][0]

        if method == "update":
            print "Help: " + self.update.__doc__

myClass = myClass()
myClass.help()
```

It works, but as my methods collection grows it will be a pain in the ass to make the help work as intend. Is there anyway to call something like `self.method.__doc__` dynamically? Thanks.

Comment: a good solution would possibly achieved using `decorators`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using this:

```
if method == 'update':
    help_string = self.update.__doc__
```

you could use more flexible solution:

```
help_string = getattr(self, method).__doc__
```

Just make sure that you catch `AttributeError`s (it will be thrown when there is no method with given name).

Comment: @FilipeKiss: Awesome :) You are welcome. If you have something more complex, it may be a good idea to consider [jterrace's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17223209/548696) of using [argparse module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse) to build CLI argument parsing part. However, sometimes it is better to keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
method = sys.argv[2:3][0]  # This is a bit odd; why not sys.argv[2]?
print "Help: " + getattr(self, method).__doc__
```

Comment: I actually use sys.argv[2:] since I get everything from the second element forward. I added this to test the documentation I forgot to edit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use argparse for this:

```
import argparse
import inspect

class myClass(object):
    """description for program"""

    def update(self):
        """update method help"""
        print 'update command'

    def something(self):
        """something command help"""
        print 'something command'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    program = myClass()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=program.__doc__)
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(program, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
        subparser = subparsers.add_parser(name, help=method.__doc__)
        subparser.set_defaults(method=method)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.method()
```

Example on the command line:

```
$ python ~/test/docargparse.py --help
usage: docargparse.py [-h] {something,update} ...

description for program

positional arguments:
  {something,update}
    something         something command help
    update            update method help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help          show this help message and exit

$ python ~/test/docargparse.py
usage: docargparse.py [-h] {something,update} ...
docargparse.py: error: too few arguments

$ python ~/test/docargparse.py update
update command

$ python ~/test/docargparse.py something
something command
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
import inspect

class T:
    def test(self):
        '''test'''
        pass

for t in inspect.getmembers(T, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
    print t[1].__doc__
```

should scale pretty well.